# Excel VBA [Complex .formulaR1C1 not working]

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

Here is my line of code:

`ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "='Main'!R[9]C[0]&LEFT(""     "",5-LEN('Main'!R[9]C[1]))   &'Main'!R[9]C[1]&"" ""&DAY('Main'!R[4]C[8]) & ""-"" & UPPER(TEXT('Main'!R[4]C[8],""mmm"")) & ""-"" &YEAR('Main'R[4]C[8])&"" "" & 'Main'!R[9]C[3] & "" "" & 'Main'!R[9]C[4] & "" ""  & LEFT('Main'!R[9]C[5],35)& LEFT(""                                   "",35-LEN(LEFT('Main'!R[9]C[5],35))) & "" "" & LEFT(""            "", 12-LEN('Main'!R[9]C[6]))& 'Main'!R[9]C[6] & "" "" & 'Main'!R[9]C[7] & ""          "" & LEFT('Main'!R[4]C[9],9) & LEFT(""         "",9-LEN(LEFT('Main'!R[4]C[9],9))) & ""                      "" & 'Main'!R[9]C[2] & LEFT(""    "",4-LEN('Main'!R[9]C[2])) & "" DATALOAD"""`

I'm getting a `run-time error 1004` saying its an `application-defined or object-defined error`. The problem is I'm not super familiar with VBA. There is quite a bit of stuff going on in this formula. Essentially all I need is to paste data onto a new sheet in an EXACT format. That's why there are a bunch of spaces and such. I use `R1C1` because each row has different data on sheet 1 and needs to be pasted into sheet 2 accordingly.

Any ideas on why this code is running into an error? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

For clarification: My whole macro is as follows...

```
Dim row As Integer
Dim col As String
col = "A"
row = 1
Do Until IsEmpty(ActiveCell) 
     Sheets("Protected").Select 
     Range(col & row).Select 
     ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "big long code as mentioned above goes here"
     Sheets("Main").Select
     ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select 
     row = row + 1
```

**Copied From Comments**

The actual working formula is

`=Main!A11&LEFT(" ",5-LEN(Main!B11)) &Main!B11&" "&DAY(Main!$D$6) & "-" & UPPER(TEXT(Main!$D$6,"mmm")) & "-" &YEAR(Main!$D$6)&" " & Main!D11 & " " & Main!E11 & " " & LEFT(Main!F11,35)& LEFT(" ",35-LEN(LEFT(Main!F11,35))) & " " & LEFT(" ", 12-LEN(Main!G11))& Main!G11 & " " & Main!H11 & " " & LEFT(Main!$E$6,9) & LEFT(" ",9-LEN(LEFT(Main!$E$6,9))) & " " & Main!C11 & LEFT(" ",4-LEN(Main!C11)) & " DATALOAD"`

Comment: The best way is to first type the formula in an excel cell and then port it to VBA. Can you type it in Excel and show us what are you trying?

Comment: your problem probably stems from using `activecell` rather than specifying the sheet and cell, but it is hard for me to know for sure

Comment: If i understand you correctly, you are saying to make sure it works as a regular formula first? It was originally created as a formula, yes. Then i translated it into VBA lingo.

Comment: Can you post your regular formula?

Comment: =Main!A11&LEFT("     ",5-LEN(Main!B11)) &Main!B11&" "&DAY(Main!$D$6) & "-" & UPPER(TEXT(Main!$D$6,"mmm")) & "-" &YEAR(Main!$D$6)&" " & Main!D11 & " " & Main!E11 & " "  & LEFT(Main!F11,35)& LEFT("                                   ",35-LEN(LEFT(Main!F11,35))) & " " & LEFT("            ", 12-LEN(Main!G11))& Main!G11 & " " & Main!H11 & "          " & LEFT(Main!$E$6,9) & LEFT("         ",9-LEN(LEFT(Main!$E$6,9))) & "                      " & Main!C11 & LEFT("    ",4-LEN(Main!C11)) & " DATALOAD"

Comment: Also, i do specify which cell in the macro above. Everything works perfectly. If i replace that huge line of code with ="WORKS FINE" then "WORKS FINE" is placed in the desired locations. Its when i plug in that huge line of code that something goes wrong. For that reason I know it is that line that has an issue.

Comment: What are you trying to get from 'LEFT(" ",5-LEN(Main!B11))'? It will return either one space character, " ", or none, "". Don't you want to use REPT ("repeat") instead of LEFT?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you have a working formula then the best thing to do is record a macro to see how Excel stores the formula in the cell.

This is what I got from the macro

`ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=Main!R[10]C[-3]&LEFT("" "",5-LEN(Main!R[10]C[-2])) &Main!R[10]C[-2]&"" ""&DAY(Main!R6C4) & ""-"" & UPPER(TEXT(Main!R6C4,""mmm"")) & ""-"" &YEAR(Main!R6C4)&"" "" & Main!R[10]C & "" "" & Main!R[10]C[1] & "" "" & LEFT(Main!R[10]C[2],35)& LEFT("" "",35-LEN(LEFT(Main!R[10]C[2],35))) & "" "" & LEFT("" "", 12-LEN(Main!R[10]C[3]))& Main!R[10]C[3] & "" "" & Main!R[10]C[4] &" & " LEFT(Main!R6C5,9) & LEFT("" "",9-LEN(LEFT(Main!R6C5,9))) & "" "" & Main!R[10]C[-1] & LEFT("" "",4-LEN(Main!R[10]C[-1])) & "" DATALOAD"""`

You can compare this formula with your formula and see where was what missing :)

Comment: Okay so what exactly did you do? I guess i don't understand how you "port" your formula over to vba. I understand how to record and such, but i think im missing something here. Would you mind explaining this process? The above solution worked, btw.

Comment: Simply record a macro and then insert the working formula in the cell. Once done, stop the macro. The VBA code will get automatically generated in a Module. :)

Comment: You should accept this as the answer. If you do a comparison of this text and what you had, you'll see where it went wrong. I recommend using [Beyond Compare](http://www.scootersoftware.com/) or something similar.